# After enough(200) epochs, LSTM LM return only <pad>, <unk>, 'the' token with Nan loss

Tags: pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I constructed Bi-LSTM Language Model by `pytorch`, and found that after 200 epochs, the model suddenly returned only meaningless tokens with Nan loss, while it returned reasonable tokens before.

Please refer to the code of model below:

```
# optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.009,  amsgrad=False)

class BiLSTM(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, voc_size, hidn_size, emb_size=300):
        super().__init__()     
        self.voc_size = voc_size
        self.emb_size = emb_size
        self.hidn_size = hidn_size
        self.emb = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=voc_size, embedding_dim=emb_size) 
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=emb_size, hidden_size=hidn_size, bidirectional=True) 
        self.lm_out = nn.Linear(hidn_size*2, voc_size) 
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.3)
        
    def forward(self, x, prev_state):
        state_h, state_c = prev_state
        bs = len(x)
                
        emb = self.emb(x)
        emb = emb.permute(1,0,-1)
        out, (state_h, state_c) = self.lstm(emb, (state_h[:,:bs,:].contiguous(), state_c[:,:bs,:].contiguous()))
        
        forward_out = out[:, :, :self.hidn_size] 
        backward_out = out[:, :, self.hidn_size:]
        concat_h = torch.cat([forward_out[:-2], backward_out[2:]], dim=2) 
        
        final_out = self.lm_out(self.dropout(concat_h.permute(1,0,2)))  
        
        return final_out.view(final_out.size()[0]*final_out.size()[1], final_out.size()[-1]), (state_h, state_c)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by `exploding gradient`.
I found this by checking layer's gradient and weight:

```
model.lm_out.weight
>>>
tensor([[nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        ...,
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan]], 
       device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)

model.lm_out.weight.grad
>>>
tensor([[nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        ...,
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan]], 
       device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)
```

So I edit my code like:

```
loss.backward()
torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1)
optimizer.step()
```

It solved my problem.

Comment: Are you sure that you want your LM to actually generate `pad` tokens? If this is a valid output, you're making it harder for the network to train, given that you probably have a lot of these tokens and that they are quite likely to be predicted. Normally you would just sample words in a loop until an `end` token and avoid generating actual pads.

Comment: @runDOSrun Thanks for your advice. I was not considering `pad`, and your comment make me realize it is wrong not to have done that. I input one full IMDB review(a set of sentences), in this case I guess I should have: 1) added <eos> token at the end of each input review data, 2) not calculated generated tokens' loss after <eos>, 3) and additionally I should have sampled some tokens from generated review to calculate the loss, is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that would certainly be correct for your taken approach! There's also other very different ways one can go about it, but it depends on what type of text you want to generate and its structure. E.g., for a typical LM, you don't need a sentence structure in the batches. If you're predicting word-by-word, the input can be on word-level as well, so that you don't need paddings (e.g. by inputting the entire document or random slices of it). The <eos> position (end of doc/sent) can then be used to indicate the output structure.

Comment: @runDOSrun Thank you for your guidance. Now I can understand how to code LM properly :)